# How to log installation message using ansible-playbook with homebrew

Tags: ansible, homebrew

I wrote an ansible role with the following task to install app with homebrew (.yaml):

```
- name: Install libraries with Homebrew
  homebrew:
    name:
      - zsh
      - vim
      - python
      - ...others
```

It works well but the console didn't print the installation results for each library. It only shows the result of the whole task:

```
TASK [osx : Install libraries with Homebrew] *****************
ok: [localhost]
```

but I expect it prints out all module names and their states like this:

```
TASK [osx : Install libraries with Homebrew] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (name=zsh)
changed: [localhost] => (name=vim)
ok: [localhost] => (name=python)
```

I wanna know how to log installation results in the console using ansible-playbook with homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, [the module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/homebrew.py#L577) actually eats stdout and stderr almost every time it is invoked. It will return stderr occasionally, but I didn't see any time it returns stdout

Since it is [community supported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/homebrew.py#L18), the best I know to offer is to [file an issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/new/choose) asking for the change.

The work-around is to just use `- command: /usr/local/bin/brew install {{item}}` which *will* give you back `stdout` and `stderr`, with the bad news being that you will have to manage the idempotency by hand :-(